# XRDP from windows 10 machine to UBUNTU 18.04 audio not working

Tags: sound, remote, xrdp

I am using XRDP in UBUNTU 18.04 to connect from a windows 10 desktop audio not working . But audio works locally . I am new to Ubuntu. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have sound redirected to your Windows machine when using xRDP, you will need to compile the sound module for xRDP.  This feature is not enabled by default in the xRDP package shipped with Ubuntu 18.04.

**1/ Easy way....**

You can try to perform a custom installation using this script (see https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13663

You simply download the script, you mark it as executable and you issue the following command in a terminal session

**

> ./install-xrdp-3.0.sh -s yes

**

You have then to SHUTDOWN and Boot your machine after the script has finished running...Rebooting might not be enough to enable sound redirection

**2/ Manual installation**

You should read (till the end) the following post which explains how to manually enable sound redirection for Ubuntu while performing a remote desktop connection (see https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12469

In a nutshell,

**Step 1** - Enable Source code repositories in the Ubuntu software & Updates Application

**Step 2** - Download Pulse Audio File and compile

> cd /tmp
>
> sudo apt source pulseaudio
>
> cd /tmp/pulseaudio*
>
> sudo ./configure

**Step 3 - Build the pulseaudio Module**

> cd /usr/src/xrdp-pulseaudio-installer
>
> make PULSE_DIR="/tmp/pulseaudio-11.1"

**Step 4** - Install the pulse audio Module

> install -t "/var/lib/xrdp-pulseaudio-installer" -D -m 644 *.so

**Step 5** - Test your configuration

Hope this help
Till next time